# leaflet blank screen on meteor but not on single nonmeteor test.html

Tags: javascript, meteor, maps, leaflet, openstreetmap

I´m using leaflet on meteor but its only showing a blank (grey) map without displaying the map tiles. when I test the script locally in a single html file its working.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
test
<div id="map" style="height: 180px;"></div>
123
<script>

    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);


    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);

    var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup("some text :)");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but its not working when I try to do it in meteor.
my meteor setup:

I have a main.html where I declare some CDNs:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-1.0.0-b1/leaflet.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-1.0.0-b1/leaflet.css"/>
</head>
```

I also use iron:router to route. so there is a map.html with a map template where I only have my

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

I also have setup my #map{height: 180px;} in my stylesheet.

So now I have to run the script with some javascript with my Template.map.rendered function

```
Template.map.rendered = function () {

    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.Icon.Default.imagePath = "/images/leaflet/";


    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);

    var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup("some text :)");


};
```

But it will not work. What is causing the blank map error? my browser console is not showing any error.

Comment: Why did you use the 1.0.0 version in your meteor app instead of the 0.7.3 one?

Comment: this was just a small hack to see if its just a problem with 0.7.3. so its also not working with the 1.0.0-b1 and 0.7.3 for me in meteor.

Comment: Well I have to say I am curious, as I have pretty much the same code as yours and never had a problem. Here's my version (using another tile server) if you'd like to try: `var map = L.map('map',{center: [51.505, -0.09], zoom:13, maxZoom:18}); L.tileLayer("https://otile{s}-s.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg", {subdomains: "1234"}).addTo(map);`

Comment: I know its strange. I have done this also in an other meteor app and its working fine but not in this one. your code is also still not working. I have tested several tilemaps but its not working. I also dont have some special packages installed that cause the error. When I dont load the leaflet.js the map is not showing so I know leaflet.js is loaded correctly. But I had a Problem in other nonmeteor projects with leaflet and jquery. so jquery have to be loaded first otherwise it shows the blank map container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I figured out what was the problem. I have a reset.css where I have some reset rules for my UI.

this line was producing the error:

```
div, a, p, img, blockquote, form, fieldset, textarea, input, label, iframe, code, pre {
    some stuff,
    some stuff,
    overflow:hidden;   <---------
}
```

so it looks like `leaflet` don´t like divs with `overflow:hidden` option